# Alienware m17x recovery

Tags: windows-7

I am having trouble setting up an Alienware m17x after a complete re-installation of Windows 7 Professional x64.

I cannot increase the screen resolution beyond 1024x1020 and I can't install the Nvidia driver for the graphics card. A message appears during setup saying hardware was not detected. I can't recover from the recovery partition because that was overwritten during the installation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can download the all of your laptops's drivers from Alienware's website.  http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/Product/alienware-m17x-r4

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd install the driver from Dell's website, as found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/alienware-m17x?driverId=R279499&osCode=W764&fileId=2731114241&languageCode=EN&categoryId=VI). Then you should be able to install the NVIDIA driver from their website.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not sure if the graphics card is a nvidea Geforce GTX 280M. I don't have the invoice from ordering online anymore. The graphics card doesn't show up in system information!

Comment: It's a 680M, but Dell's site has the drivers that would be installed. If the machine accepts the drivers then at least you have an NVIDIA chip which the installer will recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Install the chipset drivers first if you haven't already done so. I normally use the latest ones from the Intel website but for your machine you'll need the manufacturer ones provided in the link (which are new anyway). I'd then install the integrated Intel graphics driver before the Nvidia one. There is also a new BIOS update that is recommended according to the Dell website.

Finally, as already mentioned, you may need to install the manufacturer provided Nvidia drivers rather than Nvidia's own (at least without modding them).

Comment: I installed the chipset drivers, but when I'm attempting to install the integrated graphics driver I get an error saying that my laptop does not meet minimum requirements? I don't understand...

Comment: I've just noted that the link in Ramhound's comment is for the M17x R4 but your question states M17x. The latter is a dual AMD and Nvidia GPU set up and an Nvidia chipset i.e it will need Nvidia chipset drivers also. Are you definitely on the right Dell support page for the downloads. If you're not clear about your specs use the service tag on the Dell site to search for the drivers.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I visited the right support page.

Comment: So it is definitely a M17x and not an M17x R4? Have you been trying to install Intel chipset drivers? It needs Nvidia chipset drivers. The service tag is printed on the bottom by the way. This the the link for the USA support page for the M17x (dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/alienware-m17x)

Comment: When I install the chipset driver I get this message:
http://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-179266-231251/Untitled.png


I'm installing the drivers that come on the Resource CD.

Comment: @Justin, I'm lost. Can you please clarify the exact model of your laptop. If you can't be sure then use the service tag printed underneath and type it in at the [Dell support website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19?c=us&l=en&s=dhs). That way you can be sure you're using the correct and most up to date drivers with the correct OS. Do not try and install drivers blindly without knowing they are the correct ones for the correct model.